# js slider - how to set up handle to negative margin?

Tags: javascript

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ELKHq/, now I would like to set up minimum to for example `-50px` and also I would like get opportunity to move handler a little next to parent div (`#szyna`) from the right side... I **must** use that script http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/slider/ .
Thanks in advice.

EDIT:
Here is both example what I would like to do with my slider:
(remove spaces in below links)

http:// i.stack.imgur.com/jP5Zm.png

http:// i.stack.imgur.com/Hcrb6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#start{
     margin-left: -50px;
}
```

should set the margin. It works in Chrome and Firefox at least.

**EDIT:**
Updated to match the images posted in the edit: http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/ELKHq/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works but now unfortunetly `#start` couldn't get a little out of `szyna` on the right side... I shuld mention about it in question....

Comment: Hi dieeying, could you rephrase, not sure if I understand?

Comment: If the goal is to that the slider can move 50 pixels to the right and the left of the `szyna` div, it does that right now, at least when I'm trying it. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/ELKHq/1/ does what you're showing in the image, I believe?